# spring boot redis Lettuce exception

Tags: java

After the project has started once, visit after 10 or 20 minutes

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @GetMapping(value = "test")
    public String test(){
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("test-work", "hello,163");
        return (String) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("test-work");
    }
}

server.port=8081

spring.redis.host=Remote IP
spring.redis.password=**
spring.redis.timeout=300000
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-active=8
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-wait=-1
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.min-idle=0
spring.redis.lettuce.shutdown-timeout=200

redis-server.conf

bind 127.0.0.1 Remote IP

protected-mode yes

port 6379

tcp-backlog 511

timeout 600

tcp-keepalive 300

daemonize no

supervised no

pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid

loglevel notice

logfile /var/log/redis/redis.log

databases 16

save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes

rdbcompression yes

dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /var/lib/redis

slave-serve-stale-data yes

slave-read-only yes

repl-diskless-sync no

repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no

slave-priority 100

requirepass***

appendonly no

appendfilename "appendonly.aof"

appendfsync everysec

no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no

auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb

aof-load-truncated yes

lua-time-limit 5000
reids-server.conf

slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128

latency-monitor-threshold 0

notify-keyspace-events ""

hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64

list-max-ziplist-size -2

list-compress-depth 0
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10

aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Redis exception; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisException: java.io.IOException:
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44)
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:268)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceHashCommands.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceHashCommands.java:471)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceHashCommands.hVals(LettuceHashCommands.java:371)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.hVals(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:980)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.lambda$values$11(DefaultHashOperations.java:219)
```